# How can I make an object/class inaccessible to Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, code-security

I am building an API for minecraft called the [Quantum API](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/wip-mods/2344753-the-quantum-api-a-better-alternative-to-forge-and). We all know that reflection can be used to do some nasty stuff to classes, and even cause undefined behavior if used without care.

Is there a way to make classes and objects immune to reflection? Perhaps with a security manager? Or vice versa, restrict a certain list of classes/objects from using reflection?

My use would be to prevent other mods that are loaded with this API from using reflection to change a RuntimePermission in a SecurityManager, and to prevent modification of minecraft's base classes (and objects) at runtime, as well as the API's own classes (and objects).

Comment: Not that I am aware of, and I question the benefit of such things - even if you block that, it's fairly trivial to modify the code itself if your goal is to mess around with game internals.

Comment: Remember what happened months ago between Asie and LexManos? She used a coremod to modify Forge code. EDIT: sorry I forgot this is stackexchange, so you may or may not remember. But it's an example.

Comment: No, I don't even know what game you refer to, and do not understand the vague implications you imply.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SjNjVe72

Comment: Again, that is near meaningless. If you are motivated enough to hack a game, you don't need reflection to do it.

Comment: I'm not the one using reflection to do it. It's for security's sake to make sure a mod does not use reflection. My API never uses reflection unlike other modding APIs. The point isn't just to hack the game, the point of this API is backward compatible mods on an abstraction that never touches the original game file at all.

Comment: You're willfully missing the point. If you run my code, I can have my code modify minecraft's base classes, reflection or no. Trying to prohibit reflection (if it's even possible) doesn't gain you anything - all it does is waste your time.

Comment: I'm not _willfully_ missing the point. I just don't know what you mean. I understand you can modify the base classes without reflection; you can simply edit the jar file and insert your own files. What I'm trying to prevent is a mod changing values and access for certain methods and fields. All class transformations are done through a Java Agent mod loader which is severely limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29).  It doesn't prevent reflection, but it'll make it *practically* impossible (technically, someone could still do it but it'll take them far more effort to figure it all out) for someone to figure out what part of the code does what, as it'll (amongst other things) scramble the names of functions.

You can usually set exclusions, such as functions that need to be publically accessible for an API.

Unfortunately, it'll only work for your own code, and not Minecraft itself, but it's the best practical solution I can think of.

Otherwise, I think there might be a solution that involves making your own custom loader for Minecraft with a SecurityManager that sandboxes everything and prevents reflection, but I'm not entirely sure if that's possible.  You may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/770635/disable-java-reflection-for-the-current-thread) question on StackOverflow which discusses that possibility further.

Comment: +2 for the idea of obfuscation -2 for "not an option for APIs", +1 for telling me exactly what I plan to do with the API and sending me a useful question. :)

Comment: Personally me disassembled and cracked so much obfuscated Java applications (for Android) that I can say: obfuscation doesn't give any serious protection against professional cracker.